# Django serializer validation 'TypeError: create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create ip_port which is a ManyToMany relation in my UserRequestForm model but in create() method i am getting an error that 'TypeError: create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str'

```
views.py
class UserRequestFormView(GenericAPIView):
    renderer_classes=[UserRenderer]
    permission_classes=[UserPermissions,]
    queryset = UserRequestForm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRequestFormSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['request_to_provide']
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        data=request.data   
        serializer=UserRequestFormSerializer(data=data)
       
        
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # breakpoint()
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
            # print(serializer.data)
            sdata=serializer.data
            return Response({'detail':'User Request Form created successfully','created_data':sdata},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
serializers.py

class UserRequestFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ip_port = serializers.ListField(source="ip_port.id", allow_null=True, required=True)    
    district=serializers.CharField(source='user.district',read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model=UserRequestForm
        fields='__all__'
        read_only_fields=['user','district']

class IPPortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ip_port_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)    
    class Meta:
        model=IPPort
        fields='__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ipport=validated_data.pop('ip_port')
        user=UserRequestForm.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if ipport:
            print(ipport['id'][0])             # printing the list as [{"id": 80,"ip_port_id": 80,"ip": "11.11.123.11","port": 33333,"date_from": 2022-01-01,"date_to": 2022-01-31,"time_from": 09:00,"time_to": 10:00}]
            ls=[]
            for i in ipport['id'][0]:
                print(type(i))                 # printing type str
                # user.ip_port.create(**i)
                ls.append(IPPort.objects.create(user=user, **i))   # giving error on this line
            user.ip_port.set(ls)            
        return user
```

Comment: try to switch to Raw -> Json in Postman (instead of form-data)

Comment: hello @VitAmin i want to test it in form-data only. Is there any other way to do that also i have edited my problem can you please help me now?